# How to divide a search query into sub queries?

Tags: google-analytics

I am just wondering if there is an algorithm that can divide a user input query for a search engine into a set of sub queries.
for example if the entered query is 
"plcae to stay and eat"
the sub queries would be 
"place to stay" and "place to eat".
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The specification has to be more precise I guess. Ideally, this would need an NLP algorithm.